# How to cross-compile with Meson and a Python dependency?

Tags: python-3.x, cross-compiling, meson-build

I'm trying to cross-compile an application using Meson. The application has a Python dependency.
I'm building on a Linux system (the build machine) and I'm building a Windows executable (the host machine).

I cannot make Meson detect the Python dependency.

This is what I have tried. My meson.build is using Meson's Python module:

```
pymod = import('python')
python = pymod.find_installation('python3')

pybind11_include_dir = include_directories('./include')

pybind11_dep = declare_dependency(
    compile_args : [
        # see https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1604
        '-fsized-deallocation',
        '-fvisibility=hidden'
    ],
    include_directories : pybind11_include_dir,
    dependencies : [
        python.dependency()
    ],
)
```

This works when I build a native Linux executable. When I cross-compile for Windows I have a Windows version of Python locally. I point to that in my cross_file.txt like this (I left out the mingw64 toolchain parts and host and build machine settings):

```
[binaries]
python = '/home/user/src/mingw/py38/python.exe'

[built-in options]
c_args = ['-I/home/user/src/mingw/py38/include', '-L/home/user/src/mingw/py38']
cpp_args = ['-I/home/user/src/mingw/py38/include', '-L/home/user/src/mingw/py38']
```

Now when I run  `meson setup build_win64 --buildtype=debugoptimized --cross-file cross_file.txt` meson finds the python executable, but then tries to execute. Which won't work because it's a Windows binary:

```
Program python3 found: YES (/home/user/src/mingw/py38/python.exe)
OPENING: ['/home/user/src/mingw/py38/python.exe', '-c', "import sysconfig\nimport json\nimport sys\n\ninstall_paths = sysconfig.get_paths(scheme='posix_prefix', vars={'base': '', 'platbase': '', 'installed_base': ''})\n\ndef links_against_libpython():\n    from distutils.core import Distribution, Extension\n    cmd = Distribution().get_command_obj('build_ext')\n    cmd.ensure_finalized()\n    return bool(cmd.get_libraries(Extension('dummy', [])))\n\nprint (json.dumps ({\n  'variables': sysconfig.get_config_vars(),\n  'paths': sysconfig.get_paths(),\n  'install_paths': install_paths,\n  'version': sysconfig.get_python_version(),\n  'platform': sysconfig.get_platform(),\n  'is_pypy': '__pypy__' in sys.builtin_module_names,\n  'link_libpython': links_against_libpython(),\n}))\n"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
-- snip ---
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/user/src/mingw/py38/python.exe'
```

The Meson Python module documentation does not mention cross compilation at all.

What is the correct way to make Meson find the Windows Python dependency settings under Linux?

Comment: If you get an answer to this, please let me know, I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: We gave up on this, so unfortunately I have no answer.